# Oracle vs db2 create user and table

Tags: db2

I'm learning to use the command line db2 to create a simple table.

Oracle will perform the following steps:

```
CREATE USER user IDENTIFIED BY password;
```

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO user;`
and then just type `CONNECT` and login, and you can create tables.

All this in DB2 how? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB2 has different user management than Oracle. DB2 relies on the operating system or solutions like LDAP, there is no `CREATE USER` command.

I recommend that you start by reading this [IBM RedBook about commonalities and differences between the DB2 and Oracle](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247736.html) and how to get started.